# JSLT: output non-JSON

Tags: json, jslt

I'm interested in JSLT as a means for transforming JSON (there's an excellent video by Lars Marius Garshol on the design and implementation of [JSLT](https://vimeo.com/289470470)).  However, in addition to outputting JSON, I'd like to be able to output any other Text format like I can with XSLT, e.g. delimited records, fixed column formats, etc.

In JSLT, I'd like to be able to do something as follows to generate a pipe delimited record:

```
    let name = .customer.name
    let address_street = .customer.address.street
    let address_city = .customer.address.city
    let address_state = .customer.address.state
    let address_postcode = .customer.address.postcode
    let pipechar = "|"

    $name
    $pipechar
    $address_street
    $pipechar
    $address_city
    $pipechar
    $address_state
    $pipechar
    $address_postcode
```

For fixed column-width fields, I would wrap the elements in a function that pads/trims it to a specified width. To output XML, I could enclose the $ variables within an XML text structure.

I'm wondering if this is possible or how I could extend JSLT to do so.  Thanks.

Update:
Using string concatenation works with variables and JSON elements. E.g.

```
    $name +
    $pipechar +
    .customer.address.street +
    $pipechar +
    etc...
```

XML can be formatted using tags as strings, also using string concatenation:

```
    "<root>" +
        "<message>" + $msg + "</message>" +
    "</root>"
```

It would be better to not do this but implement something similar to the XSL output method:

```
   <xsl:output method="text"/>
```

or

```
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it I guess would be to make a JSON format for delimited files, transform to that, and then have a generic piece of code that writes the delimited file.

Of course, as you note, you can also produce a string that is a delimited file as output, but performance is probably not going to be great. The most efficient solution is probably to make an array where each line is a string, and then join on `"\n"`.

There's no plans for any `output=text` feature in JSLT itself, although if more people ask for it we could consider it.

It's an interesting feature request. I never thought of this myself.